# Как управлять backpressure в readable stream node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных

Добрый день.

У меня вопрос по backpressure в readable stream. На сайте nodejs есть статья https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/. Там говориться что backpressure может быть не только в writable, но и в readable stream. Но к сожалению, там описано только, как не надо делать:

```
// This is problematic as it completely ignores return value from push
// which may be a signal for backpressure from the destination stream!
class MyReadable extends Readable {
  _read(size) {
    let chunk;
    while (null !== (chunk = getNextChunk())) {
      this.push(chunk);
    }
  }
}
```

Как надо - не написано.  В интернете я смогла найти только такой вариант: http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-04-nodejs-readable-streams.html

```
let i = 10;
const rs = new Readable({
  highWaterMark: 500, // для создания backpressure
  read(size) {
    const data = 'In Node.js I\'m using the fs.createWriteStream method to append data to a local file. In the Node documentation they mention the drain event when using fs.createWriteStream, but I don\'t understand it.\n';
    let ready = true;
    while (ready) { // продолжать только, если push возвращает true
      if (i < 0) {
        this.push(null);
        ready = false;
        return;
      }
      const buf = Buffer.from(data);
      i--;
      ready = this.push(buf);
      console.log(ready); // будет переодически false
    }
  },
});
```

Не могу понять как работает этот код. Тут же нет события drain, как в writable streams, так что узнать, когда можно снова вызывать _read, мы можем только вызвав сам _read и посмотрев, что он вернет (true или false) - но на этот момент кусок информации мы уже отправили, не зная есть backpressure или нет. Таким образом, получается, что мы выходим из цикла только для того, чтобы опять вызвать _read, не зная рассосался там затор или нет.

Может кто-нибудь пояснить, что на самом деле происходит при вызове _read? Может есть другие методики работы с backpressure в readable stream?

Comment: В документации же написано, что `_read` не нужно вызывать. Его вызовет нода когда принимающая сторона будет готова к новой порции данных.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я запуталась. Тогда схема такая: 1) мы вызываем this.push(), пока буфер не заполнится и this.push() не вернет false, 2) выходим из метода _read, 3) метод _read потом снова вызывается node, когда буфер опустел?

Comment: Да. Примерно так.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться